# Code of opencv's RGB2LAB function for android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I want to see logic behind opencv's(android) function RGB2LAB. How I can see that or where can I find code of this function in opencv(android). I have calculated L,a,b values and now I want to convert these values into 8 bit or 16 bit image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name already suggests, OpenCV is opensource.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp